# 1.16.5 water is clear and f3 screen is bugged

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

In 1.16.5 I was bored and logged onto Minecraft for the first time in a few months. when I looked at my old f3 screen it looked like and old 1.8 version. The water was also clear. I had no potion effects and already tried `/gamerule reducedDebugInfo false`. What do I do?

Comment: can you provide us with a screenshot of the issue, so we know what we're looking for?